# Leading eigenvalues of large sparse unsymmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a matrix $R$ which is sparse and all eigenvalues are -ve with a zero eigenvalue. Size of R is more than $10^6 \times 10^6$. But I need to calculate only few large (by value not by magnitude) eigenvalues and eigenvectors including zero (say $1000$). Which one is the **best algorithm** with better convergence and less error. Can you please suggest **few papers** for the same.

Comment: http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/ and the forked https://github.com/opencollab/arpack-ng

Comment: A safe approach might be to first compute the spectral radius $\rho$ of $R$, then compute (e.g., using the linked ARPACK) the (shifted) eigenvalues of $R+\rho$ (the shift guarantees that no eigenvalues of $R+\rho$ have negative real parts). However, such a shift can influence negatively the convergence rate of the eigensolver (due to the decrease of the relative gaps between eigenvalues). Also note that obtaining $1\mathrm{k}$ eigenpairs of a $1\mathrm{M}\times 1\mathrm{M}$ matrix can be quite costly (just storing the eigenvectors in double precision would require about 7.5GiB).

Comment: For references, you can consult the documentation of ARPACK or `doc eigs` in MATLAB.